# ¿Cómo devolver un la sumatoria de ciertos campos de una tabla vía Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

tengo una tabla con una serie de columnas numéricas y necesito devolver vía Elocuent una columna que sea la sumatoria de tres campos de la misma tabla, a continuación, les muestro la estructura de la tabla y que es lo que necesito devolver.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo debería armar la consulta vía Elocuent para que me devuelva todos los registros pero además, me genere una columna con la sumatoria de las columnas C1_01, C1_02 y C1_03 llamada totParcial, por ej?.

```
    $tbSnej1 = Snejtabsnej1::paginate(5);

    $totParcial = 0;
    foreach ($tbSnej1 as $it){
        $totParcial = ($it->C1_01 +$it->C1_02 +$it->C1_03 );
        //aquí debería armar el array con todos los campos mas $totParcial
        //¿como debería armar el array para devolverlo en el return?
    }
```

Esto es lo que estaba intentando hacer, es decir, recuperar los registros y luego, mediante un foreach, recorrer y construir el campo sumado que necesito. Ahora bien, estoy trabado en como construir un array asociativo para devolver esta estructura tal como la devolvería el propio Elocuent.

Comment: Agrega lo que hayas intentado al momento por favor

Comment: Hablas de una sumatoria parcial ¿por columna o sumando los valores de todas en una sola?

Comment: Quiero sumar los valores de las tres columnas en una, pero para cada registro, por ejemplo, para el id 1, devolver todos los campos tal como está, mas una nueva columna que contenga la suma de los valores 8+35+8=51. Lo que se me había ocurrido era hacer la consulta, recorrerla con un foreach y devolver un array construido a mano, pero como no conozco en profundidad Elocuent decidí poner esta pregunta.

Comment: Ese es un punto de partida y ayudaría a entiquecer tu pregunta mostrando lo que hayas tratado, en función de ello la comunidad te podrá proponer una eventual respuesta, te invito a tratar de armar dicha query y colocar aqui lo que hayas obtenido como resultado (así sea un fallo)

Comment: Lo que hayas intentado así como una muestra de la salida que esperas va en la pregunta, edita por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considero que desde *SQL* puedes resolver la necesidad planteada, llevando a cabo lo siguiente:

```
Snejtabsnej1::selectRaw('id, 
                        anioRelev, 
                        provincia_id, 
                        SUM(C1_01 + C1_02 + C1_03) AS totParcilal,
                        aqui_tus_demás_columnas_separadas_por_comas
                        ')->groupBy(
                            'id',
                            'anioRelev',
                            'aqui_tus_demas_columnas_no_calculadas_separadas_por_coma'
                        )->get();
```

- Con ayuda de la [función de agregación `SUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_sum) obtenemos el valor calculado en una nueva columna a la cual le podemos dar un alias
- Como además de la sumatoria necesitas el resto de columnas, puedes incluir el resto en la petición por medio [del método `selectRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#selectraw)
- Finalmente realizas una agrupación